# Adding specific permission to users with different roles in django

Tags: python, django, user-roles

I am new to django and I am a bit confused on how the permission works, or if that is what I am supposed to use in my case.

So, I have my user/model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
  ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (0, ('Student')),
        (1, ('Proffesor')),
        (2, ('Administration'))
     )
role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=2)
```

And then I have my views in election/views.py:

```
class MainPage(View)

class ElectionList(LoginRequiredMixin, View)

class ElectionDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, View)

#only administration can create elections
class CreateElection(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView)
```

How can I restrict a simple user (student, for example) to create an election?

Answer (score 3):

Django already has a [`Permission` and `Group` models and per-group permissions,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) so the cleanest "django compatible" way here would be to define "Students", "Professors" and "Administrators" as groups, setup their permissions (eventually adding custom ones if needed), add your users to the appropriate group(s), and test if your current user has the needed permissions for a given action using the [`permission_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) or since you're using a class-based view [the `PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin).

As a side note: since you're using `ints` for your `role` values, you may want to add pseudo_constants for them in your model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  ROLE_STUDENT = 0
  ROLE_PROFESSOR = 1
  ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR = 2

  ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ROLE_STUDENT, 'Student'),
        (ROLE_PROFESSOR, 'Professor'),
        (ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR, 'Administration')
     )
```

So you can query / filter your model using sensible human-readable values instead of magic numbers, ie:

```
students = User.objects.filter(role=User.ROLE_STUDENT)
```

instead of

```
students = User.objects.filter(role=0)
```

But if you use `contrib.auth.models.Group` for permissions you may not even need this field at all, as you can get your queryset from the groups members.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UserPassesTestMixin`

eg.,

```
class LoginAndPermission(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_student

    def get_login_url(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            # User is logged in but does not have permission
            return "/permission-denied-url/"
        else:
            # User is not logged in
            return "/login/"

class ElectionDetail(LoginAndPermission, View):
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution could be an alternative of Django's Decorator.
I'm pretty interesting by your question.

When I have function in my views and I don't want to display this one to a user group, I have a templatetags file :

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 

register = template.Library() 

@register.filter(name='has_group') 
def has_group(user, group_name):
    group =  Group.objects.get(name=group_name) 
    return group in user.groups.all()
```

Then, in my HTML file :

```
{% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
   <li><a href="{% url "edited" %}">Some part</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

I think it's possible in my templatetags to user permission directly in my views.py file, but I don't know How to do that.
Anyway, my method works very well up to now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Read the Permission and Authorization documentation in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin
class AddElectionPermission(AccessMixin):
    raise_exception = True
    permission_denied_message = 'permission deny'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.role != 0:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super(AddElectionPermission, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

#only administration can create elections
class CreateElection(LoginRequiredMixin, AddElectionPermission, CreateView)
```